# issue when flutter widgets padding

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

so, im beginner in flutter and im trying to code a ui like above and all its fine but i have issue in widget padding, like u see in the code below i use columns in scaffold and each widget in a container, the problem is when i set a padding in any container all widgets effect !!! im very confused. thanks for your time

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaI2E.png)

code :

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/BG.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              'h a y l o u l a',
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  letterSpacing: .5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 24.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'sign in',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: .5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_rounded),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign in',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        letterSpacing: .5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 24.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Don\'t have an account ? ',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: .5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 24.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'sign up',
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: .5,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
```

}

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8FHy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your stack with container the give your container a padding of symetric....

Answer (score 0):

put each config on the parent widget, Those configurations will affect all child widgets.
you put all your column widgets in one container if I set padding on this parent container so all child columns have this padding.

Your question is not very clear.